# Memory Exception When Merging Large Volumes of Waveform Data Files Using wrdb.wrsamp()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to merge multiple waveform data (.dat) files into a single file. I'm using the `wrdb.wrsamp()` function for this task. The total number of files is approximately 10,000 and each one has 3 channels. I've tried several times, but every attempt results in a memory exception, requiring more than 40GB of memory. I'm unsure if I am doing something incorrect.

I've been unable to find a method to write the files incrementally. My current approach is to read each sample, combine all signals into an array, and write them. While this works fine with a small number of files, I'm having difficulties when it comes to larger datasets. Each file contains over 6 minutes of data.

Comment: Your RAM can not contain all these files together which is the case when you start add them to a larger array one-by-one. Try to use numpy memory mapping to files or HDFS library in python. The logic is that you need to fill the RAM memory with only the read file then write it to a disk and flush then take the next one ...

Comment: @user2586955, thank you for your response. Yes, however, the problem arises when attempting to write a NumPy array into a waveform database (db) file. The files load into memory without any problems, but when I invoke wfdb.wrsamp() to write to a single file, it consumes a significant amount of memory. I attempted using the float16 data type, but unfortunately, the issue remains the same.